# How to change the grails version using command line?

Tags: windows, bash, grails, command-line, path

Currently i am working on a multi project groovy project with Grails framework. All projects need Grails version 3.1.9 but, a single project which needs Grails version 2.4.3.
i am building a gradle build using bash command from another directory, using that same bash command i want to change Grails version 3.1.9 to 2.4.3
currently i am using below command to change version:

```
setx -m GRAILS_HOME "E:\Softwares\grails-2.4.3"
```

but its not working,
when i use `%GRAILS_HOME%\bin` in path it doesn't recognize grails command . I am new with these bash command, any help.

```
ERROR: Access to the registry path is denied.
```

I am working on **WINDOWS 7**

Comment: There is http://sdkman.io/ - since you tagged the question with bash i assume you are running cygwin etc.  There where also a windows version of sdkman in the past. Another way out is to use the wrappers (grailsw.bat, gradlew.bat) that are added by default in new projects.

Answer (score 1):

The best option for managing multiple Grails versions is [SDKMAN](http://sdkman.io/). If you're running Windows you can run this via some shell emulator like Cygwin, or alternatively there's a Powershell clone [posh-gvm](https://github.com/flofreud/posh-gvm) that runs on the Windows command line.